# Как создать строковой буфер на 256 символов в Visual C++?

Tags: c++

Как создать строковой буфер на 256 символов в Visual C++?

Comment: Можно поконкретнее?

Comment: char buf[256];

Answer (score 2):

Стандартно в C/C++:

```
char buffer[256] = {0}; // 256 символов, включая завершающий нуль
```

или (C++):

```
char *buffer = new char[256];
```

или (C):

```
char *buffer = malloc(256);
```

Comment: Возможно, имеется ввиду массив строк(каждый элемент типа string).

Answer (score 1):

На стеке:

```
char a[257];
char* d=alloca(257);
```

Память освобождается автоматически при выходе из функции.

В куче:

```
char* b=new char[257];
char* c=(char*)malloc(257);
//... Используем
//Не забываем освободить:
delete[] b;
free(c);
```

Используя класс std::string:

```
std::string str;
str.reserve(256);
```